# .NET Core <select> With Default Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razorengine, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

My **goal is to generate a `<select>` dropdown with a certain select value (`<option>`) pre-selected**, so the finalized `HTML` should look like this:

```
<select>
  <option value = "1">Option1</option>
  <option value = "2" selected>Option2</option>
  <option value = "3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

Note that the option with a value of 2 has a `selected` attribute, indicating that it will show before the dropdown is clicked. I cannot (and am trying to) achieve this using .NET Core Tag Helpers.

This is my model (I think you can safely ignore the details):

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Pick a form")]
  public IEnumerable<Form> AvailableForms { get; set; }

  public Form SelectedForm { get; set; }

  public List<ReportData> FormResponses { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the `Form` object there just has `Id` and `Name` properties on it.

This is my select statement:

```
<label asp-for="SelectedForm.Name" class="form-control-label font-weight-bold"></label>
<select asp-for="SelectedForm.Name"
        class="form-control"
        onchange ="onFormSelected(this.value)"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AvailableForms, "Id", "Name"))">
</select>
```

I don't see the answer in the [Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper)
Or in a [blog on the topic](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx)

Comment: Is this for a default "empty" state or are you trying to display a selected value (such as user preference which has been chosen already)?

Comment: @James The user picks a form on another page. This page (with the markup) above then gets loaded. The purpose is so they can pick another form for a report if they want to. So, in short, I have the id of the "default" form in the controller before the view loads.

Comment: The `asp-for` value will determine what is initially selected.

Comment: Thanks @CalC, trying that now. I was before, assumed that was the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need to is set the select to use the `SelectedForm.Id` property, then specify the value of the form to be selected in your controller.  I had to update your code a little but this works for me -

```html
<label asp-for="SelectedForm" class="form-control-label font-weight-bold"></label>
<select asp-for="SelectedForm.Id"
        class="form-control"
        onchange ="onFormSelected(this.value)"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AvailableForms, "Id", "Name"))">
</select>
```

Then in your controller

```
var vm = new ReportViewModel()
{
    AvailableForms = new List<Form>()
};

var form2 = new Form() { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" };
(vm.AvailableForms as List<Form>).Add(new Form() { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" });
(vm.AvailableForms as List<Form>).Add(form2);
(vm.AvailableForms as List<Form>).Add(new Form() { Id = 3, Name = "Baz" });

vm.SelectedForm = form2;

return View(vm);
```

Comment: Asp.net core will bind the attribute of asp-for,

Answer (score 3):

The `SelectList` constructor can take an additional argument, namely [`selectedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_). In your case, you should be able to pass this through, which I *think* will look something like this:

```
asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AvailableForms, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedForm.Id))"
```

I think the reason `asp-for` isn't working for you is the mismatch between the value of `SelectedForm.Name` (which is a string), and the value of the `Id` property you're using in the `SelectList` constructor (which is an integer?).

You can see partially how this works in the source code. You end up [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L1603) in `GenerateOption`:

```
var selected = item.Selected;
if (currentValues != null)
{
    var value = item.Value ?? item.Text;
    selected = currentValues.Contains(value);
}
```

At this point, I believe `currentValues` will contain a single element, which will be a string (`Form.Name`). I believe also that `item.Value` will be e.g. `"1"` and so there's no match.

Answer (score -3):

This is old, but I didn't see my approach here.
Pass it in with a viewbag from the controller.

```
<select>
    <option>@ViewBag.selected</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Haha, maybe in another 3 years, I will get to use Razor again and try this out and upvote it.

Comment: If my selected value is 2, this now adds the options of 2,1,2,3. It makes it confusing to users that there are now duplicates in the list. How do you remove the duplicate?